# Is the following measure absolutely continuous relative to Lebesgue measure? (details inside)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Denote $f\left(x\right)=x^{2}$
 , we define a measure $\nu$
  on $\mathbb{R}$
  such that $\nu\left(\left(-\infty,0\right)\right)=0$
  and for every Borel set $A\subseteq\left[0,\infty\right)$
  we define $\nu\left(A\right)=\lambda\left(f^{-1}\left[A\right]\right)$
  where $\lambda$
  is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$
 . Is $\nu$
  absolutely continuous relative to $\lambda?$

I'm kind of stumped with this, every $x\in\mathbb{R}$
  has two preimages which are $\pm\sqrt{x}$
  which is obviously relevant. Suppose E
  is a set of Lebesgue measure $0$
 , I'm not sure whether it's necessarily true that $\nu\left(E\right)=0$

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$f^{-1}[A]=\left\{x\in [0,\infty) \vert x^{2}\in A \right\}\cup \left\{x\in (-\infty,0) \vert x^{2}\in A \right\}$$